# vuetify select or combobox bind item

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a list of objects:

```
var itens = 
[ {
    name: 'a',
    id: 1
},
{
    name: 'b',
    id: 2
},{
    name: 'c',
    id: 3
}
]
```

so I show in a select:

```
<v-select
  :items="itens"
  v-model="selectedItem"
  item-text="name"
  label="Cartório"
  single-line
  ></v-select>
```

so in my `this.selectedItem` have the name but I wanna to bind the whole object `{id and name}`  it`s possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You have to use `return-object` props of `v-select`

Like that :

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  v-model="selectedItem"
  item-text="name"
  label="Cartório"
  single-line
  return-object
  />
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKwQEb?&editors=101)

[Vuetify Doc about return-obejct in v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-custom-text-and-value)

Comment: is there a way when you give return-object property, to set the selected item of the dropdown with just the id-value. Now it requires the whole object as input

Comment: It's a bit short to anwser in a comment, but yes you can, using `ìndexOf` on your `items` and then setting `selectedItem` with `items[index]`